# Prolems with highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRyP7.png)

I have problem with highcharts same the picture.
I don't know why, the 0 line at left side and right side don't same on line.
Thanks all so much.

Comment: Why have you used two yAxis? By your example you can use just one yAxis and it will work as you want.

Comment: Because that's requirement from customer, please give me solution if you can, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two Y axes and want to align 0 tick together that is not yet possible with highcharts. Follow this discussion https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2554384-multiple-axis-alignment-control?page=3&per_page=20.

However you can try this simple workaround:

- Have the same min/max on both y Axes:

  yAxis: [{
      min: -10000,
      max: 40000
  }
- Or just link one axis to the other:

  yAxis: [{
      opposite: true,
      linkedTo: 0
  }

Comment: Thank you so much.